# What is the best practice to work with routers in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming

I'm wondering about the best way to use ssh to work with routers interactively in python version 2.7.

**Scenario:**

1. Access 20  devices at the same time.
2. run 10 commands on each device.
3. parse specific words from the commands output.
4. run another command based on step 3.
5. exit the devices.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free coding service. And it might be a good idea not to start a new project on good old Python 2.

Comment: Thank you for your advise @KlausD. but unfortunately my middle server that i use are not supporting python 3

Comment: If the server can run Python 2, it can also run Python 3.

Comment: more clarification: i don't have permission to install python 3 on it because i have normal user privileges

Comment: You don't need root permissions to install Python in your home.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Netmiko package ktbyers made, [here](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko).

The package allows you create ssh connections and send commands/configurations/etc.

Comment: I check Netmiko but unfortunately it doesn't support huawei devices :(

Comment: There is some amount of Huawei support in Netmiko https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/tree/develop/netmiko/huawei